# Making a DialogFragment class that implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener but I get method overriding errors

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

```
package com.example.uilab;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public static class TimePicker extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));

    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

    }

}
```

And I get an error under my class name where it says:

```
The type AddToDoActivity.TimePicker must implement the inherited abstract method TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener.onTimeSet(TimePicker, int, int)
```

This class is within another class, my main activity

my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.uilab"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.uilab.AddToDoActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Why am I getting an error with overriding the method for my picker class?

If you need some more details I can post more, but this is the part of my project where I am getting an error, just trying to implement a dialogfragment to implement a time picker.

Comment: remove the onTimeSet method and implement by add unimplement method way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must fully qualify your use of the class `android.widget.TimePicker`, used by `onTimeSet(...)`, because your class is also called TimePicker. The compiler thinks `TimePicker` refers to your class. Alternatively, rename your class.

Comment: i just had to rename my class! Dammit so simple

Answer (score 1):

The first argument of the method `onTimeSet` must be from type `android.widget.TimePicker`

```
public void onTimeSet(android.widget.TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

    }
```